# sql @ variables in .net string

Tags: c#, sql, .net

I've got a script which i use in sql management studio fine and i'm trying to get it into a .net WPF application. it uses variables declared in the query itself and rather than running two in the .net application i was wondering if it's possible to do it this way and if so what i'm doing wrong. it currently however throwing the exception "An Unhandled exception of type 'System.InvalidOperationException' occurred in Systm.Data.dll'

the query is using a test account_no value this will have multiple rows and i want to retrieve only the latest as this will have the card current value and status which is what i'm after for this field. so i'm getting the largest ACCT_TRN_ID associated with that card number as this is a primary key i don't need to use the card number on the second part. there is a anther query which brings back a detailed history if the user wants it.

```
DECLARE @v_ID INT

SET @v_ID = (SELECT MAX(ACCT_TRN_ID) FROM ACCOUNT_TRANSACTION WHERE account_no = 9826168000000131)

select NEW_ACCT_STS_CODE as 'Status', NEW_BALANCE as 'Balance' from ACCOUNT_TRANSACTION where ACCT_TRN_ID = @v_ID
```

and the .net code looks like

```
// SQL Conenction Config
SqlConnection sqlConnection1 = new SqlConnection();
sqlConnection1.ConnectionString = @"Data Source=###; Initial Catalog =USICOAL; Integrated Security=True";
// SQL Connection Config

// SQL Command Setups

SqlCommand cmd2 = new SqlCommand();
cmd2.Connection = sqlConnection1;
cmd.CommandText = ("DECLARE @v_ID INT SET @v_ID = (SELECT MAX(ACCT_TRN_ID) FROM ACCOUNT_TRANSACTION WHERE account_no = " + cardNumber + ") select NEW_ACCT_STS_CODE as 'Status', NEW_BALANCE as 'Balance' from ACCOUNT_TRANSACTION where ACCT_TRN_ID = @v_ID ");

// SQL Command Setups

sqlConnection1.Open();

DataTable data = new DataTable();
SqlDataAdapter adapter = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd2);
adapter.Fill(data);
SummaryGrid.DataSource = data;

sqlConnection1.Close();
```

the command is number 2 as in the same method i have anther query which is running fine so didn't include it here as not to cause confusion.

Comment: I think cmd.CommandText, should be cmd2.CommandText

Comment: You're not wrong... Well that's annoying been messing with this for a hour finally decided it was time to call the stackoverflow Calvary... Thanks for that I might have to buy a rubber duck before i do any more

Comment: If you get stuck like this, it sometimes helps (in my case anyway) to get away from your desk for 5 - 10 min :)

Comment: Two comments about your SQL (command text).  You are missing the single quotes around '@v_ID'.  You also need to define @v_ID as a parameter in cmd2.

Comment: I think script is different from SQL command code and you cannot simply copy. It would be better to divide into 2 commands. I'll provide simple code within around 1 hour.

Answer (score 0):

Simply try this code, please kindly remember there're many good examples on internet. I removed as 'Status' and as 'Balance' and not sure it will work fine without above 2 conditions.

```
SqlConnection sqlConnection1 = new SqlConnection();
sqlConnection1.ConnectionString = @"Data Source=###; Initial Catalog =USICOAL; Integrated Security=True";
// SQL Connection Config

// SQL Command Setups

SqlCommand cmd1 = new SqlCommand();
cmd1.Connection = sqlConnection1;
cmd1.CommandText = "SELECT MAX(ACCT_TRN_ID) FROM ACCOUNT_TRANSACTION WHERE account_no = @v_para";

SqlDataAdapter adapter1 = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd1);
adapter1.SelectCommand.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@v_para", SqlDbType.Int));
adapter1.SelectCommand.Parameters["@v_para"].Value = Convert.ToInt32(cardNumber);

int v_ID_value = Convert.ToInt32(cmd1.ExecuteScalar());

SqlCommand cmd2 = new SqlCommand();
cmd2.Connection = sqlConnection1;
cmd2.CommandText = "SELECT NEW_ACCT_STS_CODE, NEW_BALANCE from ACCOUNT_TRANSACTION where ACCT_TRN_ID = @v_IDnumber";

SqlDataAdapter adapter2 = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd2);
adapter2.SelectCommand.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@v_IDnumber", SqlDbType.Int));
adapter2.SelectCommand.Parameters["@v_IDnumber"].Value = v_ID_value;

// SQL Command Setups

sqlConnection1.Open();

DataTable data = new DataTable();

adapter2.Fill(data);
SummaryGrid.DataSource = data;

sqlConnection1.Close();
```